# How to parse data from a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint

So I am in the process of building a new screen for my application (built using Verivo App Studio - uses the same syntax / expressions as the .NET Framework) that will link items directly from the SharePoint list to be view able in the App.

This has all been no problem so far, however, when I pull the data down from SharePoint, some of strings (such as the title of a document) come with extra characters, in varying length, at the start (such as 132;#Titleexample). When viewed in SharePoint, these additional characters are not present. After some searching, it seems SharePoint uses ;# in a similar fashion that a CSV file uses commas.

My question is; *is it possible to parse the string (either on the SharePoint side {creating a new view?}, or from within the Verivo App studio side {though it seems it has limited parsing functionality}), so that I can display the data correctly*? Keep in mind the additional characters are of varying length, could be 123;#Title or 1;#Title, so a simple SUBSTRING function won't suffice. If there was a function to pick up the string after the # key, it would be great!

I am new to this so apologies if I have left out anything obvious. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code are you using to retrieve the values from SharePoint? Usually the values you describe come from fields that have complex datatypes, such that their values each have both an ID value and a text value. Depending on your code, you may be able to explicitly retrieve the text value directly instead of the string representation of the ID and text value mashed together.

Comment: This would not be a SharePoint issue, but rather a question of how to use Verivo, and its ability to retrieve data. As to your assertion on the sub-string approach I would disagree; first get the position of # within the string with something like a char-index function, then retrieve sub-string by starting from that position.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! @Thriggle I am not really using any code, I have set up a data source within VerivoAppstudio, which pulls the information from the SharePoint list, and creates a copy of it locally. Then from within App studio I simply put in (eg) 'http://appstudio/SharePoint/' + Filename into the Data textbox (Filename-the string I'm hoping to parse) under properties. I was thinking of using an IF statement, but Im not sure I've got the syntax right: `IIF(Filename LIKE 'string;#', SUBSTRING(Filename , 2, 100), Filename )` . The logic being if it doesn't find # subtract 1 character

Comment: @Ricardo Thank you also! I've tried the char index function briefly but i'm not sure its supported by Verivo, I will play around it more, using that with Substring does seem like a good method (if I can get it working), thanks!